# Orientation issue in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, orientation, iphone-5

I have an app created for `iPhone 4s` and the previous version.Everything working fine except `iPhone 5`. I have set both Portrait and portrait `upsidedown` for iPhone and all orientation view for iPad.My problem is,handle orientation is not working in iPhone 5 but working well in the previous versions.Am facing this problem after I upgraded my `xcode` to support `iOS 6`.

Also I have found some solutions  that, to use these methods

"

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

"

instead of

"`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`
"
 method...

After using this also, I facing the same problem...So what should be my problem and what can I do to overcome this?

Pls help.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation doesn't work in iOS 6.So use supportedInterfaceOrientations method for the orientation in iOS 6 & shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for iOS 5 and earlier.
Here is the following code :

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)    
      return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ;    
  else     
     return YES;    
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|
            UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
   else       
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;       
}
```